# fetching multiple data using firebase/firestore on the server side (nextjs/apiRoutes) =problem => output before the data is ready

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, server-side, next.js

the result[] will be executed before the data is ready. i even tried to solve the problem with promise but also not successfull..

```
import { firestore } from "../../../firebase";

export default (req, res) => {
  firestore
    .collection("category-filters")
    .where(req.query.categoryKey, "==", true)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      let result = [];

      querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        firestore
          .collection("payment-accounts")
          .doc(doc.id)
          .get()
          .then(item => {
            if (item.data().creditAmount > 0) {
              firestore
                .collection("professional-profiles")
                .doc(item.id)
                .get()
                .then(endresult => {
                  result.push({ id: endresult.id, ...endresult.data() }); // executes successful
                });
            }
          });
      });

      res.json({ result }); // the data is outputted before the "querySnapshot.docs.map" is executed...
      // therefore received a blank array (result)
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work (untested):

```
export default (req, res) => {
    firestore
        .collection("category-filters")
        .where(req.query.categoryKey, "==", true)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {

            const promises = [];
            const paymentAccountsRef = firestore.collection("payment-accounts");

            querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                promises.push(paymentAccountsRef.doc(doc.id).get());
            });

            return Promise.all(promises);

        })
        .then(paymentAccountsSnapshotsArray => {

            const promises = [];
            const professionalProfilesRef = firestore.collection("professional-profiles");

            paymentAccountsSnapshotsArray.forEach(snap => {
                if (snap.data().creditAmount > 0) {
                    promises.push(professionalProfilesRef.doc(snap.id).get());
                }
            });

            return Promise.all(promises);

        })
        .then(professionalProfileSnapshotsArray => {

            const results = [];

            professionalProfileSnapshotsArray.forEach(snap => {
                results.push({ id: snap.id, ...snap.data() });
            });

            res.json({ results });

        })
};
```

You need to manage the parallel documents fetches with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and chain the different Promises returned by `Promise.all()` in order to send back the response only when all those asynchronous operations are completed. In your current code, you are sending back the response **before** those asynchronous operations are completed.

---

Also, you may need to fine tune this code in order to check that the different snapshots Arrays are not empty. This part is up to you!

Comment: Dear Tarnec, thank you soooo much!!! your code runs bug- free!